# Preventing UIImagePicker memory problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, nsoperationqueue

I am having  tough time with getting UIImagePickerController to work. It always crashes with memory error. These are the things I have done. Please advice what I can do differently.

I am using NSOperationQueue to do the save operation in a different thread.

I am not passing the UIImage which can be large, so I write the image to photo album and pass the NSURL of the asset.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSMutableDictionary *mutable = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] mutableCopy];
    NSBlockOperation *saveOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
      [[MyViewController defaultAssetsLibrary] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[chosenImage CGImage] metadata:mutable completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageSelected:)]) {
            [self.delegate imageSelected:assetURL];
        }
      }];
    }];
    [saveOp setCompletionBlock:^{
    }];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperation:saveOp];
  }]; 
}
```

Comment: @matt I had used dispatch_async but it had the same problem. This code works fine on iPhone 4,5,6. It crashes only in iPhone 6+